# jqgrid not loading data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

i've got a RoR app that's pushing out json data to a jqgrid. the grid loads up, shows the proper page/row counts, but doesn't show any rows.

data:

```
{
"total":333,
"page":1,
"records":3333,
"rows":[
    {"id":"267","cell":["42883","Enhancing Personal and Organizational Creativity (XP)","1"]},
    {"id":"268","cell":["42883","Enhancing Personal and Organizational Creativity","1"]},
    {"id":"266","cell":["42815","Strategic Decision Making (XP-Elective)","1"]},
    {"id":"265","cell":["42811","Strategic Planning","1"]},
    {"id":"264","cell":["42809","Best Practices in Innovation (XP)","1"]},
    {"id":"260","cell":["42808","Grave to Cradle - The Basics of Restructuring and Bankruptcies","1"]},
    {"id":"261","cell":["42808","Corporate Restructuring","1"]},
    {"id":"262","cell":["42808","Grave to Cradle Corporate Restructuring","1"]},
    {"id":"263","cell":["42808","Failure  - Grave to Cradle Corporate Restructuing (XP)","1"]},
    {"id":"259","cell":["42800","Competitive Strategy  (XP)","1"]}
    ]
}
```

html:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
  url:courseSource + "/fulldata?instructor=" + instrId + "&course=" + courseId,
  datatype: 'json',
  mtype: 'GET',
  colNames:['Course Number','Course Title', 'Number of Instructors'],
  colModel :[
    {name:'course_no', index:'course_no', width:200},
    {name:'name', index:'name', width:500},
    {name:'ins_count', index:'ins_count', width:260, align:'right'}
  ],
  pager: '#pager',
  rowNum:10,
  rowList:[10,20,30],
  sortname: 'course_no',
  sortorder: 'desc',
  viewrecords: true,
  caption: 'Courses'
});
```

any ideas? i'm beyond lost here - i've got the common problems tackled - the locale is loaded before the jqgrid.js, the css is loaded, jquery and friends are loaded. what's goin on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have some small problem outside of the code which you posted in your question. Compare your full HTML page with [the following page](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/kolosy.htm). It has exactly your code and your JSON data. You can see that all work without any problem. So the problem which you describ must be **outside** of the posted code.

Comment: looks like the issue is with the current build of chromium. your page works great in safari, but doesn't in chromium. see here for screenshot: http://kolosy.com:810/jqgrid.png

Comment: what's more - this only manifests on my build of chromium (6.0.398.0 (46565)) on os x. chrome, firefox 3.6, firefox 4 and safari work just fine.

Comment: @kolosy: Sorry, but your question was about jqGrid and not about retro versions of exotical web browsers. I downloaded the current version of Chromium web browser (version 10.0.622.0 (70153)) and my example work in the browser without any problem under Windows 7. So I recommend you to try update your Chromium browser. Good luck.

Comment: yup - that was it. i was under the impression that i was running the latest build, but i guess i had one from april. oops. current one works though. thanks.